# C++ vector of pairs

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, stl

I have a vector of pairs. 
I want to order the pairs in such a way that pair with the least difference between them is the first element. eg.

```
(1,10),(2,5), (5,8), (1,2), (8,10)
```

After sort:

```
(1,2), (8,10), (2,5), (5,8) , (1,10)
```

I tried like this but I am getting a run time error:

```
bool compare(const pair<int, int>&i, const pair<int, int>&j)
{
    if( (i.first-i.second) < (j.first-j.second) )
        return i.first < j.first ;
    else 
        return j.first < j.second;
}
```

Comment: What runtime error ? What code is calling this ? Try to provide a minimal complete code example.

Comment: Hehe. Complete misreading of the question lead me to write this creative bit: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9fb36b7fba6d4a9

Comment: Usually, especially with sort, you would want to use a function object instead of using a comparison function directly, because calls to function objects' operator() can typically be inlined. The function object basically implements one of the functions the guys here suggested as comparison function via operator(). In c++11 you can use the function<...> template.

Answer (score 3):

I think your comparison function is incorrect. To achieve sorting you'd need something like:

```
bool compare(const pair<int, int>&i, const pair<int, int>&j)
{
    return abs(i.first-i.second) < abs(j.first-j.second);
}
```

Comment: its working. but can you tell the thought process that lead to this. i am just learning advanced stl

Comment: In your program, you are computing the difference of firsts and the seconds and checking the difference. However, according to your answer requirement, you need to compare the difference between the elements of a single pair.

Comment: Yes, you want the function to compare two pairs by the difference of its values. Thus, it should return true if the first pair has a difference smaller than the second pair. The call to abs() is just their to take the absolute value of the difference. If i.first is 2 and i.second is 1, then i.first-i.second equals -1. However, the difference between the two is abs(-1), which is 1.

Answer (score 2):

Your comparison operator is not good as it is not both transitive and asymetric.  Transitive essentially means that it if you have three pairs a,b and c for which `compare(a,b)` is true, `compare(b,c)` is true then `compare(a,c)` should be true. Asymmetric means that if `compare(a,b)` is true then `compare(b, a)`  should be false. If you want to compare first by the difference and then lexicographically use someting of the sort of:

```
bool compare(const pair<int, int>&i, const pair<int, int>&j)
{
  if( (i.first-i.second) != (j.first-j.second) )
    return i.first - i.second< j.first - j.second;
  else 
    return i < j;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code which makes use of C++14 auto feature in lambda expressions:

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <cstdlib> // for std::abs(int)
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>


int main()
{
  using namespace std;

  vector<pair<int, int>> v = 
  { {1,10}
  , {2,5}
  , {5,8}
  , {1,2}
  , {8,10}
  };

  auto abs_distance = [](auto const& v) { return abs(v.first - v.second); };

  sort( v.begin(), v.end()
      , [&abs_distance](auto const& lhs, auto const& rhs)
        { return abs_distance(lhs) < abs_distance(rhs); }
      )
  ;

  for(auto const& p: v)
    cout << "("<< p.first << ", " << p.second << ") ";
  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

You can compile it using, e.g. clang with:

```
clang++ -std=c++1y main.cpp
```